# Django isn't consistently logging... view caching?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

I am running Python2.7, djangoappengine and AppEngine 1.6.5

My problem is that my logging.debug() messages aren't being consistently printed to the output. I've stripped my code back to a really simple homepage view

```
def home(request):
    logging.debug("Serving homepage")
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        template = 'home-loggedin.html'
    else:
        template = 'home.html'
    return render_to_response(template, locals(), RequestContext(request))
```

The idea is that I would see "Serving homepage" consistently in the log output. However, it is only logged the first time and not on subsequent hits.

```
DEBUG    2012-04-27 17:33:02,616 views.py:8] Serving homepage
INFO     2012-04-27 17:33:02,711 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-27 17:33:02,848 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[ .. Lots of 200 responses for my JS and CSS ..]
>> LOOK NO DEBUGGING LINE :(
INFO     2012-04-27 17:33:10,758 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-27 17:33:10,844 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2012-04-27 17:33:10,854 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[ .. Lots of 304 Not Modified for my JS and CSS ..]
```

I'm not caching the view in my urlconf, I have memcached enabled in my settings.py but I'm not using it yet.

The actual pain I am feeling is in a module with more advanced logic where I am unable to follow the execution of the code due to the debug not being logged.

Any help appreciated

Comment: I haven't seen this problem - most likly the logging.debug() line is not executing.  Is it possible memcache is actually working?  Have you tried using a debugger to make sure that line is actually running?

Comment: @dragonx Well - it does run that debug() line on the first load of the page. My guess was caching but I can't see any configuration where this would be enabled.

I grepped through my settings.py and I haven't seen any evidence that it is being used, unless djangoappengine enables it by default.

Debugging not my strong point but I think I'll be going there next. Thanks

Comment: Interesting, I'm debugging in Eclipse/PyDev and the debugger is stopping inside my home() function so I reckon the problem is deeper into the logging library... I'll keep digging.

Comment: ...and using the debugger I can see that something (appengine or djangoappengine) is forcing the logging level from 10 (logging.DEBUG) to 20 (logging.INFO) which is making me lose my lines. Simples! Thank you @dragonx

Comment: learn to love the debugger!  glad you figured it out!